# iOS & iCloud File Aliases?

Tags: ios, icloud, alias

Anyone have any luck using iCloud file aliases with iOS Files?? Seems the aliases created on the Mac are nothing more than nearly empty text files that are useless in iOS?

Comment: Please edit your question with what you are trying to accomplish. As it stands your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

An alias is merely a shortcut to another file or folder, so it doesn't have any "file size" other than what is sufficient to create the alias.